# Unable to import jar in scala console to run spark programe

Tags: scala

I am using scala 2.11.8, when i am using require to import jars i am getting below issue.

```
scala> util.Properties.versionNumberString
res7: String = 2.11.8

scala> :require /home/muralee1857/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.gson/gson/jars/gson-2.4.jar
The path '/home/muralee1857/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.gson/gson/jars/gson-2.4.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message:

```
x cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.
```

signifies that either you have already loaded the jar or there is another package loaded which is conflicting with the names.

Try running the following in the spark console:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val mapJson = "{ 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd' }"
val map = new Gson().fromJson(mapJson, classOf[java.util.Map[String, String]])
```

If you get import errors this means you don't have the gson package loaded.

Comment: i have changed my code as per your code like below, now it is working perfectly.                                                                                              import com.google.gson.{GsonBuilder, JsonParser}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

val tweets = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/tweets1/tweets_1499457170000/part-00000")
for (tweet <- tweets.take(5)) {
  println(new Gson().toJson(new JsonParser().parse(tweet)))
}

Comment: Is there is a way to forcefully include a newer jar, excluding the earlier one presents?